# Spinning docker image into multiple containers

Tags: docker, containers, circleci

I am working on building automated CI/CD pipeline for LAMP application using docker.

I want image to be spinned into 5 containers, so that 5 different developers can work on their code. Can this be atained? I tried it using replicas, but it didnt worked out.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
   build: .
   ports:
    - "8080:80"#    
deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4
```

Error which i get:

> :#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail docker-compose up ERROR: The Compose file
>   './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Additional properties are
>   not allowed ('jobs' was unexpected) You might be seeing this error
>   because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a
>   supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service
>   definitions under the services key, or omit the version key and place
>   your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1. For
>   more on the Compose file format versions, see
>   docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file Exited with code 1 –

Also, from different container, can developers push, pull and commit to git? Will work done in one container will get lost if image is rebuild or run?

What things should i actually take care of while building this pipeline.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I get your question. Can you please add more details on how you spawned replicas and why it didn't work? And a little bit more detail on what you wanna achieve.
Looks like you want developers to work inside a Docker container and push code from there. Is that it?

Comment: yes, i want an image to be spinned into 5 dufferent container, which will be used by developers. I can create different containers using docker run -name <container-name> <image>, but i want to do it in automated fashion. not manually. Edited question and added docker-compose.yml which uses 'replica' . I am not even sure if this replica is for spawning multiple containers or services

Comment: You're going in the right direction. Replicated mode creates five separate replicas of the image and you can use all those containers. What's the problem in that?

Comment: i am building pipeline using CircleCI, whenever i run image, i get error in circleCI (edited in question). Also, i could not see replicas getting created when i run docker container ps

Comment: Is this your complete compose file? Because apparently, your compose file is erroneous.

Comment: yes, this is complete compose-file. I was testing it for a very small application. Where do i need to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, build your image separately using a `Dockerfile` with `docker build -t <image name>:<version/tag> .` then use following compose file with `docker stack deploy` to deploy your stack.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
   image: <image name>:<version/tag>
   ports:
    - "8080:80"#    
   deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4
```

`deploy` attribute should be inside a service because it describes the number of replicas a service must have. It is not a global attribute like `services`. That seems to be the only problem in your compose file and `docker compose up` is complaining about this when running from the pipeline.

### Update

You cannot run multiple replicas with a single `docker-compose` command. To run multiple replicas from a `compose.yml`, create a swarm by executing `docker swarm init` on your machine.

Afterward, simply replace `docker-compose up` with `docker stack deploy <stack name>`. `docker-compose` simply ignores the `deploy` attribute.

For details on differences between `docker-compose up` and `docker stack deploy <stack name>` refer to this article: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-23-docker-compose-vs-docker-stack

Comment: Yes, it worked now, there is no error, when i use docker run. But still i cant see 4 containers. there is only one

Comment: What does `docker ps` return?

Comment: docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d2971c04e6ef        new:new               "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        80/tcp              elated_lamport

Comment: Try `docker ps -a` and post the result if it is different.

Comment: It is not different, the same which i got with docker ps

Comment: i have read somewhere concept as orchestrartion. Can i use it here?

Comment: Yes. Orchestration will always be an option but I'm trying to see the possibility of using `docker-compose` to do this.

Comment: I updated the answer. Give it a try and let me know. @newbie

Comment: docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml test
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Creating network test_default
Creating service test_web
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided

Comment: Anyway, it'd be better if you build your image from a `Dockerfile` separately using `docker build -t <image name>:<version/tag> .` That way, you won't have to have code in the directory where `docker stack ..` is run and you won't have `build: .` in your compose file then.